# Getting WPF to update a bound list of DataTables

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datatable

I have a tabbed widget that is bound to a `Dictionary<string, DataTable>`. The tab names are bound to the Dictionary `Keys` and the tab contents are bound to the `DataTables`. This all loads fine, but at some un-specified point after construction, all of the tables are reconstructed as a much bigger more complicated tables. My problem is how do I provide the change notification so that WPF updates the tables correctly?

It seems like a pretty obvious thing to do, and I'm wondering if I'm missing something or do I really need to use an observable dictionary construction or a customised DataTable wrapper with change notification?

Solutions I have tried so far:

- Using an `ObservableCollection< KeyValuePair<string, DataTable>` and adding or removing entries. This actually works fine, but ends up with the visually un-appealing effect of tabs disappearing and re-appearing when a table needs to get updated
- I can obviously hack it using code-behind, but would like to avoid this if possible.

Here is the XAML

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding StringToDataTableDictionary}" >
  <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Label Content="{Binding Key}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
  <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <igDP:XamDataGrid DataSource="{Binding Path=Value}"
    </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, no collection notification mechanisms solved my problem. I guess this is because behind the scenes, WPF holds a reference to the DataTable, and that is the reference that needs to provide change notification. I realise that I could have removed and re-added the table to the collection, but this was causing too much GUI slowness. So, I built a DataTable wrapper that provided change notification, see here:

```
public class DataTableWithNotification : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DataTable _theTable = new DataTable();

    public DataTableWithNotification()
    {
    }

    public DataTableWithNotification(DataTable dt)
    {
        _theTable = dt;
    }

    public DataTable Table
    {
        get { return _theTable; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void ChangeTableAndNotify(DataTable newTable)
    {
        _theTable = newTable;

        OnPropertyChanged("Table");
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So at the end of the day, you need a class that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `IEnumerable` (such as `ObservableCollection`, or `ICollectionView`). But of course, you could just make one up yourself. The main thing is that you implement both interfaces in your class, and then invoke `CollectionChanged` when the collection changes.

A simple example:

```
class MyObservableDictionary<T, U> : INotifyCollectionChanged, IEnumerable
{
    Dictionary<T, U> items = new Dictionary<T,U>();

    public void Add(T key, U value)
    {
        this.items.Add(key, value);

        // Update any listeners
        if (CollectionChanged != null)
            CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    // This is from implementing INotifyCollectionChanged
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    // This is from implementing IEnumerable
    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        // Dump the entire collection into a 'yield return'. C# will automatically
        // build an enumerator class from it.
        foreach (KeyValuePair<T, U> item in items)
            yield return item;
    }
}
```

As you can see, when I add an item I make sure that `CollectionChanged` isn't null (that is, someone is monitoring this class for collection changes) and then I invoke it. That prompts the monitoring object to call `GetEnumerator`. In the `GetEnumerator` function I just do a for each and 'yield return' each item (which tells c# to automatically build an enumerator so I don't have to do it myself).

The XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="{Binding Key}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding Value}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Yeah, I see what you're saying, but this doesn't solve my problem because my collection doesn't actually change, just the DataTable inside the collection.